# How to flip lines and change keys in JQ

Tags: json, key, jq, reverse, latitude-longitude

I'm creating a interactive map of my campus, the ideia is to replicate what I did on uMaps, [in this link](http:////umap.openstreetmap.fr/pt-br/map/mapa-interativo-furg_354207?scaleControl=false&miniMap=false&scrollWheelZoom=false&zoomControl=true&allowEdit=false&moreControl=true&searchControl=null&tilelayersControl=null&embedControl=null&datalayersControl=true&onLoadPanel=undefined&captionBar=false). The geojson was downloaded from UMap and I'm using the coordinates that came with it.

My first issue is my coordinates in the json, originally were a GeoJson, are sorted wrongly, my long came first then lat, thus when parse Google Maps can't read properly.

Json:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Almoxarifado / Patrimônio"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -52.163317,
              -32.075462
            ],
            [
              -52.163884,
              -32.075467
            ],
            [
              -52.163883,
              -32.075336
            ],
            [
              -52.163321,
              -32.075332
            ],
            [
              -52.163317,
              -32.075462
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
   {
    ...
   },
   {
    ...
   },
   ...
  ]
}
```

So, I have to flip the coordinates lines to proper put in my Google Maps Api.

And my second issue is chaging the "type" key to "layer", for a better sepation layers in my app.

I've tried:

```
.features[] | .["type"]  |= .["new value"]
```

How ever that changes the value and only accepts float values

Any help, advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

> flip the coordinates lines

For clarity and ease of testing, let's define a helper function:

```
# input: a JSON object with a coordinates array of arrays of pairs
def flip: .coordinates |= map(map(reverse)) ;
```

or even better - before invoking `reverse`, check the array has the expected length, e.g.:

```
def flip:
  .coordinates
  |= map(map(if length == 2 then reverse 
             else error("incorrect length: \(length)")
             end)) ;
```

To flip the coordinates, we can now simply write:

```
.features[].geometry |= flip
```

#### Part 2

> change the "type" key to "layer"

```
{layer: .type} + .
| del(.type)
```

#### Putting it together

```
{layer:.type} + .
| del(.type)
| .features[].geometry |= flip
```